# Create a form with a dynamic list of input elements

Tags: jquery, html

I'll post a image to explain what I pretend to achieve.

I'm using HTML, jQuery.

[image]

I want to have a list of inputs on the left side. At the right should be the selected itens to be submited. The arrows will work as add/delete items from the list.

Thats it, my question is: Is there a plugin or something to facilitate this?

If, no, how can I do it ? How could I start it ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a tutorial here for exactly what you are after: http://blog.jeremymartin.name/2008/02/easy-multi-select-transfer-with-jquery.html

Comment: Yes! I was looking for a right search term, thanks ;) I will check that tutorial

Answer (score 1):

Try below links. It may help you.

- http://www.senamion.com/blog/jmultiselect2side.html
- Part 1 : http://vijayt.com/Post/Move-items-from-one-listbox-to-another-using-jQuery
- Part 2 : http://vijayt.com/Post/Move-items-from-one-listbox-to-another-using-jQuery-%28Part-2%29